# Masked objects loading dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Everytime I load the dplyr package the console shows a warning message.
[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yT4L.png) Some objetcs are masked from other packages. I think this is because the objects have the same name. For example:

- Filter has this usage in dplyr package`filter(.data, ..., .preserve = FALSE)`
- Filter has this usage in stats package `filter(x, filter, method = c("convolution", "recursive"), sides = 2, circular = FALSE, init)`

How can I unmask the filter object from stats package if I need to use it?

Regards

Comment: Use `stats::filter()` - see `?\`::\``.

Comment: You can also set `filter <- stats::filter`, but then you'll need to use `dplyr::filter` if you ever use that command.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that they are simply packages that share the same name. The comments above basically answer the question already. Theoretically if you have a conflict of functions you want to avoid, you can also select which you prefer, like so:

```
library(conflicted)

conflict_prefer("slice", # the function
 "dplyr") # the package
```

And R will tell you which it will use as your primary:

```
[conflicted] Will prefer dplyr::slice over any other package
```

However that is an extra step and I prefer usually to name it explicitly like `dplyr::slice` as mentioned in the comments instead.